# Magento customer/order transferring

Tags: magento

Most of you coders most likely already have the habit of working on different platforms (development-staging-production). In the company I work with they also have these different platforms with a Magento enterprise edition (v1.9.0.0) instance deployed.

About 2 months ago our team took a database backup of the production version to start working from (rather large development project about the content (product images, descriptions, ...) and automatic product loading.

Currently all the modifications have been deployed on the staging platform, containing order information of orders that have been placed two months ago at latest.

After buying a (badly coded and full of bugs) extension for exporting and importing orders (including order information, quotes, shipping info and customer info) which does not work properly I had decided to just copy all the following tables from the production site:

- All tables starting with customer_
- All tables starting with s_
- All tables starting with sales_

I imported them on my development platform (just to try it out and **it works!** :O
All order, shipping, credit-memo and customer information is maintained and seem to be fully working and correct.

**Here comes the actual question:**
Will there be a chance of possible conflict with something order/customer-related in the future by doing this? As far as I know orders only carry relations to customers and customer addresses and not to actually products (at least I think they are linked by SKU and not by product entity_id like most things in magento)

This is proven by the fact that if you remove all products from your magento instance, all the order and customer information is maintained and fully working.

**Edit:** **This actually worked ;)**

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to copy the whole database?

Comment: @Joe Constant: Yes, we have done a lot of changes (including adding modules, attributes, attribute sets, categories and like several other back office related settings) ;)

Comment: @Anton is correct. There are areas where Magento has foreign keys setup, and there are areas where they don't. But there are still application links. The product id *is* stored in the quote/order tables and that is how Magento looks up the reference when it needs it. You are better off adding attributes through code instead of manually. Any category changes you will have to make again in production (or use an export/import process to migrate the changes)

Comment: @Joe: So you are saying that when we have like 1000 orders, all linked to different products that each order will get corrupt when we remove a certain product from the catalog? (As then the product_id will not be an existing product anymore?) We just made too many changes to do everything on the production site again. It's far more complex then I could tell you ;)

Comment: It's not that the order will be corrupted, but if Magento needs any extended information about the product it won't be available. Depending on what is being pulled, this could cause errors and block the display. The order data would still be intact, but you wouldn't be able to view that part of the order (potentially the entire order)

Comment: Did this tactic work or did you end up transferring he data a different way.  I'm in the same situation myself.

Comment: Yes this worked out just fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a bit late but I have come across this situation several times recently and this is an excellent question and it's important to be aware of it to avoid future problems with the customer/sales relationship.

At the time of writing the most current Magento version is 1.7.0.2 and yes, the habit of working with a production and development site is likely, so the transferring of new sales and customer during the development is an important step to take and shouldn't require extensions if one has even little experience with the DB, so here it goes:

- It is correct that the transferring of the **customer_** and **sales_** tables will transfer all the data correctly and safely.
- Thereafter, one MUST only update the **eav_entity_store** table's **increment_last_id** column for **each** row.

Doing the last step above avoids that the new orders, invoices, shipping or creditmemo's ignore the new ID's and assures that the new orders start from where the transferred orders left off.

It may be a bit confusing, but its a very easy step. This [Article](http://www.blog.maximusbusiness.com/2013/11/move-magento-sales-customers/) explains it more in detail in case.

Answer (score 1):

You are approaching this the wrong way around. If you have EE , then it bundles content staging procedures and you should use that for your content changing.

And yes it most certainly can cause issues, as all your relations with other order related content like sent invoices, all objects attributes might just get new entity_id 's and this will eventually end in a mess along your road somewhere.

If you add attribute sets and attributes to a large installation it's always recommended to implement those as extension setup routines so you can move your codebase and all changes are automatically populated to whatever database you might connect in the future.

Comment: This isn't just default magento content, just to give you an idea over the content I'm talking about: we have over 1k tables holding all product information next to the default magento tables, so the content I'm talking about is different from the content you mean ;); but thanks anyway. As for adding extra attributes that are required for certain modules our team is well away to use the default magento way (setup and update scripts...)

Comment: well then you asking wroong thing. You should ask how to sync two mysql databses

Answer (score 1):

There's this script:

https://github.com/iateadonut/magento_copy_customer

It grabs a customer and all his orders through the single command:

$mg->copy_customer(1234);

if 1234 is the customer_entity.entity_id - You can take a look in the source code to see how the table restraints were queried to make sure all rows were grabbed.

Comment: Is this script compatible with Magento 1.x ?

Comment: I'm sorry.  I have no idea.  I haven't worked on Magento in a very long time.  Let us know if it works for you.